# fatal: unable to find remote helper for 'masterhttps'

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, repository

i wanted to push the existing project to my github repository, rest of steps performed well but at last step its giving me error as below. so kindly if you have any solution help me with it.

- git version 2.25.1
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

```
saifullah@saifullah-IdeaPad-Gaming3-15ARH05D:~/Desktop/pro/emotion__detection/FacialExpressionRecognition$ git push -u origin master

fatal: unable to find remote helper for 'masterhttps'

saifullah@saifullah-IdeaPad-Gaming3-15ARH05D:~/Desktop/pro/emotion__detection/FacialExpressionRecognition$ git remote -v

origin  masterhttps://github.com/saifujasoor/Face-expression-recognition-with-Fast.ai-and-OpenCV.git (fetch)
```

Comment: Run `git remote -v` and copy-paste the command and its output into your question.

Comment: i have updated the question please check it sir

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

> ```
> git remote -v
>
> origin  masterhttps://github.com/[snip]
> ```

Note that this is not:

```
origin  https://github.com/...
```

but it *should be*.  To fix it, use `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/saifujasoor/Face-expression-recognition-with-Fast.ai-and-OpenCV.git`, or run `git config --edit` to edit your configuration in your chosen editor, and remove the `master` in front of the `https://` part.